# Change CMake from linking dynamic library to static library

Tags: cmake, linker, static-libraries

I'm using a Github project and it's CMake file is linking against OpenSSL's dynamic libraries using these lines:

```
target_include_directories(project PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}>)
target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
```

I've printed out both variables to give:

```
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR: /usr/include
OPENSSL_LIBRARIES: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
```

I have the static libraries libssl.a and libcrypto.a in the same path as the dynamic libraries.

How can I change the CMake script to link the static libraries instead?

Temporarily I tried hard-coding to this:

```
target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a")
```

but I got:

```
No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a'
```

Comment: read https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html

Comment: @SpacePotatoes Awesome, thanks. Please do feel free to put it as an answer.

Comment: BTW, the **actual** value of `OPENSSL_LIBRARIES` variable is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so`. Note on the **semicolon**: it delimits elements in the list variable. Your printing loses this semicolon because you don't enclose the message into double quotes. Always print variables with using **double quotes**: `message(STATUS "OPENSSL_LIBRARIES: ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}")`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for that, didn't realise!